# Java generics not complete understanding

Tags: java, list, generics, object

Here I have a question regarding Java generics. Assuming we have List data structure in the following forms:

```
List<Object>
List<?>
List<T>
List<E>
```

So, what are the differences amongst those 4 forms?
Best regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference between `List<T>` and `List<E>` is that they use a different name.  In both cases, it's a type variable that has to be defined somewhere else.

`List<?>` indicates that the list has some specific, but *unknown*, element type.  It could be a `List<String>`, a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<DeliciousPie>`.  You can't add any element except `null` to a `List<?>`, because you don't know if that object has the same type as the list's element type.

A `List<Object>` is a list that can contain any object.  You can add any element to it.